# Is there a succinct way to create a Comparator<X> based on ordering by X.getY()

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

Is there any shorter way to say this:

```
final Comparator<ClassA> byName = 
    (final ClassA a1, final ClassA a2) 
        -> a1.getName().compareTo( a2.getName() ));
```

I know that getName() will never return null.

Perhaps something along these lines using a method reference:

```
final Comparator<ClassA> byName = ????( ClassA::getName );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can shorten it to:

```
final Comparator<ClassA> byName =
                Comparator.comparing(ClassA::getName);
```